# hql query with param and pageable error "Parameter with that position [1] did not exist"

Tags: sql, spring-data, hql

Here is my native query (unfortunately i cannot use it as the native query does not work with pageable)

```
select * from stock_indicators si inner join stock st on si.stock_id = st.id where si.slope_simple_regression_10 > 1 and si.date = (select date from stock_details order by date desc limit 1) order by si.slope_simple_regression_10 desc
```

This is a corresponding hql query:

```
@Query(value = "from StockIndicators si join fetch si.stock where si.slopeSimpleRegression10Days > 1 and si.date = :date order by si.slopeSimpleRegression10Days desc", countQuery = "select count(si.stock) from StockIndicators si where si.slopeSimpleRegression10Days > 1")
    Page<StockIndicators> findWithStocksIndicators10DaysTrendUp(Pageable pageable, @Param("date") LocalDate date);
```

And this query does not work, the following error occurs:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist
```

So what i did so far:

1. Changed the order of arguments (still the same error)
2. Changed the query to include subquery, but unfortunately HQL does
   not support limit
3. Changed the date = :date part to date = ?2 (still the same error)

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution. It was my stupid mistake. I forgot to add parameter to countQuery. The correct method should like:

```
@Query(value = "from StockIndicators si join fetch si.stock where si.slopeSimpleRegression10Days > 1 and si.date = :date order by si.slopeSimpleRegression10Days desc", countQuery = "select count(si.stock) from StockIndicators si where si.slopeSimpleRegression10Days > 1 and si.date = :date ")
    Page<StockIndicators> findWithStocksIndicators10DaysTrendUp(Pageable pageable, @Param("date") LocalDate date);
```